# Populating 3 columns in an excel sheet from C#, without having repeated values across rows

Tags: c#, excel, composite-primary-key

Sorry if the question title was a bit weird. I want to populate 500 excel rows with a composite primary key which consists of 3 columns. 2 columns automatically generate random int between 1 and 50 and third is a date between 01.01.2006 and 31.12.2013. So i want to have 500 rows, each with a different combination of the 3. Here's my code

```
        Type excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");

        dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
        excel.visible = true;

        excel.Workbooks.Add();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        dynamic sheet = excel.ActiveSheet;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
        {


            sheet.Cells[i, "A"] = rnd.Next(1,50);
            sheet.Cells[i, "B"] = rnd.Next(1,50);
            sheet.Cells[i, "C"] = RandomDay();
```

**//** this is where I'd check if a combination exists and if it does assign a new one

```
            for (int j = 0; j <= i + 1; j++)
            {
               if ( sheet.Cells[j + 1, "A"] == sheet.Cells[i, "A"] && 
                sheet.Cells[j + 1, "B"] == sheet.Cells[i, "B"] && 
                sheet.Cells[j + 1, "C"] == sheet.Cells[i, "C"])
                {
                    sheet.Cells[i, "A"] = rnd.Next(1,50);
                    sheet.Cells[i, "B"] = rnd.Next(1,50);
                    sheet.Cells[i, "C"] = RandomDay();

                }

            }

        }



    }
```

// random  date method

```
    public static DateTime RandomDay()
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 12, 31);

        Random gen = new Random();

        int range = (end - start).Days;
        return start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
    }
```

I'm really not sure if this would work, plus it's running slow, it has to iterate over and over again to check if the combination exists. Does anyone have a better and faster solution? 
Thank you all!

Comment: Writting from my mobile so I can't write much. Define a range (range=sheet.Range ("A1:D20")) and then assign a 2 dimensional array to its value (range.Value=array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your constraints allow it, I would recommend generating the unique values outside of excel and then inserting them into excel, so you can put them into a Dictionary of tuples.

That way you can check for preexisting values by creating a String from your values and using it as the key in your Dictionary. Then iterate over your Dictionary values and insert them into excel.

HashTables (what a Dictionary is) are constant time for lookup, so you'll save a ton of time guaranteeing uniqueness.

```
Dictionary<String,Tuple<int,int,DateTime>> store = new Dictionary<String, Tuple<int, int, DateTime>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    int n1 = rnd.Next(1,50);
    int n2 = rnd.Next(1,50);
    DateTime dt = RandomDay();

   String key = n1.ToString() + n2.ToString() + dt.ToString();

    while (store.ContainsKey(key)) {
        n1 = rnd.Next(1,50);
        n2 = rnd.Next(1,50);
        dt = RandomDay();

        key = n1.ToString() + n2.ToString() + dt.ToString();
    }

    store.Add(key, new Tuple(n1, n2, dt));
}
```

And to add to excel just iterate over store.Values.

Comment: You could replace the while loop with a do while loop to eliminate the redundant key creation at the beginning of the for loop.